# RDLC Switch Construct - is there an Else?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting, expression, rdlc

I have the following expression within a report:

```
= Switch( Fields!RATE_CODE.Value = "First", " £/Week",
          Fields!RATE_CODE.Value = "Second", " £/Day")
```

I've searched all over but cannot find a way to add an `else` or `default` to this expression.  There doesn't seem to be any doc's on this contruct either.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `Switch` function returns the value associated with the **first expression** in a series that evaluates to true, you can use the following trick:

```
= Switch( Fields!RATE_CODE.Value = "First" , " £/Week",
          Fields!RATE_CODE.Value = "Second", " £/Day",
          1 = 1                            , "default value" )
```

Comment: Thanks - I'd literally discovered the same myself except I was using `""=""`.  You deserve the credit though.